# Multivariate supervised LSTM for for regression only (not for prediction)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, lstm

I am a beginner with machine learning. I want to get a multivariate regression model with LSTM. I followed this tutorial by Jason Brownlee:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

In that tutorial the output feature (var1) is also part of the input features, just with another time lag (t and t-1). But what if I don't have the output feature (var1) when I use the model on new data?

I want to get a regression model based on 10 input features and one output feature. I want to train the model in a supervised manner (with 10 input and one output feature). The model should then deliver an output sequence (e.g. of 100 values) based on input features. I always have input features, so I don't want to predict without input features.

Do you understand what I mean? I want to get a LSTM model in a way of a multiple linear regression model where I can get with some input values an output value. How should I prepare the LSTM model?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to get "marginal effects" like the coefficients in a linear model?

Comment: @Peter: Actually I want to have something similiar like a multiple linear (or non linear) regression, where I can input multiplte features that give one output. The built regression model I want to use on new data. Ist LSTM the right approach?

Comment: You can use neural nets for this. Actually, if I understand you correctly, you want to predict on new data. No problem. LSTM is mostly for time series. If you include lags (t-1) in the model, you would need to predict t+2 based on predicted t+1. If this works is a matter of testing...

Comment: @Peter: I agree, neural networks might be the better choice for my problem. I followed this tutorial now: https://machinelearningmastery.com/regression-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library-python/?unapproved=530301&moderation-hash=b50b189033b7a79140eb7d4b8826d2e2#comment-530301 and I could get a good regression. LSTM is for time series. I have a time series problem thats why I tried LSTM, but LSTM is mostly designed to predict futures. E.g. predict air temperature one hour ahead. At least I understood it like this. For a classic regression problem neural networks seemed to be the better choice